# How to write XPath to capture text that is not tagged

Tags: text, xpath, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrap customer reviews from a site and ran into an interesting set-up.

```
<div class="Review">
  <img class="stars" etc>
  <b>ReviewerName</b>
  - yyyy-mm-dd
  <br/>
  <p>Review</p>
  <a>was this helpful links</a>
  <hr/>
  <br/>
  <!-- Repeat above for additional reviews. -->
</div>
```

For the life of me I can't come up with an XPath that will capture the date (`- yyyy-mm-dd`), as there is no HTML formatting around it. Anyone have a solution?

Jon

Comment: @Jon: How probable is it that a programming Q&A site does not let you post code? ;-) Have a look to the right next time you edit a question, there are some helpful formatting hints in the sidebar.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a structure like this:

```
<div class="Review">
    <img class="stars"/><b>ReviewerName</b> - yyyy-mm-dd<br/>
</div>
```

The following xpath selects the date `yyyy-mm-dd`

```
substring-after(/div/b/following-sibling::text()[1],' - ')
```

Comment: The `substring-after()` is a bit assumptive about white-space that may or may not be there in the expected form. I would probably remove the dash in the "outside" programming language. Especially since most programming languages do not let you access XPath function results, only node-sets.